# User does not have permission to perform this action. When I deploy my website

Tags: sql, web-hosting

I have classic asp.net website which works very well in VS but it gives an error when I'v deployed it on aspspider.com
The error is

```
User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

I am trying to configure it out what's wrong with it.
I have also read on numerous posts about putting some tags in .webconfig or changing the user permission of the accounts. I have no Idea what this is all about.

I don't know what all information to share, please ask me for the information you want to know, I will share here.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to perform this action.

    [SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5063578
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +5077239
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +43
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +47
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +20
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +56
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   Category.binddata(String loc) in c:\MemberSites\MemberSites_AspSpider_Ws\manishgor\webroot\Category.aspx.cs:172
   Category.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\MemberSites\MemberSites_AspSpider_Ws\manishgor\webroot\Category.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

here is my webconfig file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ManishString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PrimaryDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="PrimaryDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PrimaryDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am using windows authentication to connect to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is right there in aspspider.com's forums. Aspspider.com doesn't attach the databases from app_code folder automatically, instead we have to attach databases ourselves and correct the connection string according to aspspider.com's Forum.

If you are facing the same problem with aspspider.com, Please check AspSpider.com's forum its all mentioned there and there is not any requirement of changing user permissions on databases created locally using your VS.

I hope someday this would help someone out there!!